# How can I allocate max features for counter vectorizer?

Tags: vectorization, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I created counter vectorizer with skitlearn, but got syntax error at "max_features". "max_features" worked when I created TfidfVectorizer. How can I set max features on counter vectorizer?

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',
                         lowercase=False,
                         tokenizer=None,
                         preprocessor=None,
                         min_df=2,
                         ngram_range=(1,1)
                         max_features=1000
                         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed `,` after `ngram_range (1, 1)`.

Try this :

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',
                     lowercase=False,
                     tokenizer=None,
                     preprocessor=None,
                     min_df=2,
                     ngram_range=(1,1),
                     max_features=1000
                     )
```